# Remove extra area that's being overlapped by an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I ran into an issue when following [this guide](http://www.cssjockey.com/code-snippets/an-easy-way-to-create-tabbed-content-with-jquery-css) to create a tab menu on my site. 
[image]

The content box is a bit too long and being overlapped by the image. 
Would anyone please tell me how to cut out that extra area?

Here's an [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/av9ez/2/) that illustrates the problem.

**HTML:**

```
<div class='product'>
    <div class="product_image">
        <img src="http://www.gamersgate.com/img/boximgs/big/DDB-TTCP.jpg" alt="fggf"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
            <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
            <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
            <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.</div>
        <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
            dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
        <div
        id="tab-3" class="tab-content">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
            ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
            in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</div>
    <div
    id="tab-4" class="tab-content">Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
        enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
        aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>
<!-- container -->
```

**CSS:**

```
    body{  
    margin-top: 100px;  
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', serif;  
    line-height: 1.6  
     }  
    .container{  
    width: 800px;  
    margin: 0 auto;  
    }  

    ul.tabs{  
    margin: 0px;  
    padding: 0px;  
    list-style: none;  
    }  

    ul.tabs li{  
    background: none;  
    color: #222;  
    display: inline-block;  
    padding: 10px 15px;  
    cursor: pointer;  
    }  

    ul.tabs li.current{  
    background: #ededed;  
    color: #222;  
    }  

    .tab-content{  
    display: none;  
    background: #ededed;  
    padding: 15px;  
    }  

    .tab-content.current{  
    display: inherit;  
    }  

    .product {
    font-size: small;
    }

   .product_image {
   float: left;
   width: 200px;
   padding: 20px;
   margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
   }
```

Comment: +1 For a fiddle. It makes it a lot easier on everyone :)

Comment: @TravisJ, thank you. But for unknown reason, I can't get the tabs to function on fiddle.

Comment: That is because you forgot to include jQuery (oops!). Here is an updated one: http://jsfiddle.net/fhWjz/

Answer (score 1):

If i understand right, check one here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhWjz/1/)

```
I made changes in css only
```

Answer (score 1):

Changed a bit of CSS, here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/Ur32q/)

```
.tab-content {  
  display: none;
  float: right;
  width: 584px;
  margin: 0;
  background: #ededed;  
  padding: 15px;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I use "float left" because it makes the tabs a bit closer to the picture.